# Help to understand the concept of diminishing returns

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, visualization

Suppose I have this function:

$q=f(k,l)=600k^2l^2-k^3l^3$

Then,

$f_l=1200k^2l-3k^3l^2$

$f_k=1200kl^2-3k^2l^3$

$f_{ll}=1200k^2-6k^3l$

$f_{kk}=1200l^2-6kl^3$

$f_{kl}=f_{lk}=2400kl-9k^2l^2$

Now,

If we assume that:

$f_l>0$

$f_k>0$

$f_{ll} <0$

$f_{kk} < 0$

$f_{kl}=f_{lk}>0$

$RTS = \left. -\dfrac{dk}{dl}\right|_{q=q_0}= \dfrac{f_l}{f_k}$

Then,

$\dfrac{dRTS}{dl}=\dfrac{d \left( \dfrac{f_1}{f_k} \right)}{dl} \lt 0$

when $200<kl<266$ and we say that RTS is diminishing when $kl$ is in this interval.

My question is:

I want to visually see an RTS that is diminishing and an RTS that is not diminishing. What functions and parameters do I plot?

My understanding of RTS is that it is the slope of the function $f(k,l)=c$ where $c$ is a constant. So I tried doing a contour plot for various levels of $c$ but I don't see any significant differences in the contours (all are still download sloping and slowly becomes flat). Here's the plot:

[image]

Thank you in advance for any help provided.

Comment: What is an RTS? To me that stands for "runtime system", "return to sender", or "return to stock", none of which make sense in context.

Comment: @dfeuer RTS is defined as $\dfrac{f_l}{f_k}$. The expansion of the acronym does not matter, does it?

Comment: @Amzoti sorry, there was a typo. The $t$ is actually an $l$

Comment: @mauna: I am not sure how you are defining that ratio since these are functions of two variables. Have you just plotted the function and also plotted contour plots for it to see what is going on?

Comment: @Amzoti I've edited the definition of RTS. It's the partial derivative of $q$ with respect to $l$ over the partial derivative of $q$ with respect to $k$ while holding $q$ constant. So RTS is the slope of the implicit plot of $q$, isn't it? Yes,I've also plotted the function (holding $k$ constant$ but that dosn't seem to help.

Comment: So, can you just calculate those partials and then take their ratio and 3D plot and contour plot that?

Comment: @Amzoti could you please clarify on what I need to plot? For the 3D plot, are the points suppose to be all the $(f_l,f_k,\dfrac{f_l}{f_k})$ for which $q=c$? If so, what $c$ should I use? Similar question also for the contour plot.